# Django: Frequent use of include template tag - how much is too much?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I noticed that I started using `include` template a lot. One of my template files has 20+ include tags.

Some of them are for modal dialogs that in turn have include for different form field sets. I am also using basically the same buttons with different data attributes so these are also done with `include` tags. Some my "fragments" that I use with include have around only five lines of HTML code.

I worry if this is too much and can negatively affect performance (since Django loads another files, etc..)

For example whis is markup of one of my HTML fragments I am using with `include`:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="url" class="form-control" id="video-link-input" name="video_link"
           placeholder="YouTube link">
</div>

<input type="hidden" id="video_id" name="video_id" value="">

<img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail"  id="video-img-preview">
```

Hope the question is not too broad. I would just like to avoid possible bad practice.

Answer (score 4):

Overly fragmented templates will impact your performance, but not because Django loads files.

With the default settings, Django caches template files when `DEBUG=False`:

> `django.template.loaders.cached.Loader`
>
> ...
>
> This loader is automatically enabled if `OPTIONS['loaders']` isn’t
>   specified and `OPTIONS['debug'`] is False (the latter option defaults to
>   the value of `DEBUG`).

IMHO, having lots of includes is not a bad practice in itself. The alternative would be repeating the code, which violates the DRY principle.

If you find yourself including the same template multiple times within one template, you might want to consider a [custom inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags).

If you are really worried about performance, look into caching and specifically template fragment caching.

Comment: I want to use include to separate parts of my code because my code looks too complicated. Is it bad to use include for that reason?

Answer (score 1):

According to Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/performance/#template-performance):

- using **{% block %}** is faster than using **{% include %}**
- heavily-fragmented templates, assembled from many small pieces, can
  affect performance

You can use **extends** and **block**

Few examples:
In `base.html` I use these blocks

```
...
{% block navbar %}
{% endblock %}

{% block sidebar %}
{% endblock %}

{% block searchbar %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}
{% endblock %}
...
```

Now I extend `base.html` into `login.html`. Say my `login.html` just need `navbar`, `content`, and `footer`

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<h1>Login </h1>
{% block navbar %}
   This is my navbar
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  Here is my login form
{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}
  This is footer
{% endblock %}
```

Now I extend `base.html` into `home.html`. Say my `home.html` need `navbar`, `sidebar`, `searchbar`, `content`, and `footer`

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<h1>Home page </h1>
{% block navbar %}
   This is my navbar
{% endblock %}

{% block sidebar %}
    This is sidebar
{% endblock %}

{% block searchbar %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
   This is homepage contents. This will not render which you use in login.html **content** block
{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Yes, I am using these tags for bigger HTML. For example I have base.html with basic markup, styles, JS and then use this as base for my more specific templates.